# SQLite: Select rows with time in range

Tags: java, sqlite, timestamp

I have a table where let's say we have

```
  ID  |  NAME  |  Time
  --------------------
   3  |  ex    |  15:22:00
```

From this table I want to select the rows that have  time that is between Time 14:30:00, and two hours ahead (16:30:00) so row id 3 should be selected.

What is the best way to do it, using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIME(Time) BETWEEN "14:30:00" AND "16:30:00";
```

I'm not able to test it, so I'm sorry if it's not fully functional.

As for the right way to do it in java, give us more details. Are you using JDBC, JPA, some other?